# Calling an API which needs Authentication in the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

I am creating the ASP.NET which is calling a third party API. The third party API can be accessed only giving username and password.

```
   public string Get(string LabName)
    {
        string userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
        string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
        string BaseURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"];

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            Uri uri = new Uri(BaseURL);
            client.BaseAddress = uri;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            string clarity_URL = BaseURL+"api/v2/labs?name="+LabName;
            var response = client.GetAsync(clarity_URL).Result;

            string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return responseString;
```

I am not sure how to pass the username and password while calling the API in the ASP.NET.Can anyone suggest me how to securely call the API

Comment: Do you know how your api accept user name and password? As header or as query string?

Comment: In the browser if I access the API it asks me the username password

Comment: Check the Api specifications, since username and pass could be sent in many ways. i.e. token, cookie, headers...

Comment: How do I do with headers

Comment: You can add authorization header with token. But until you figure out which  authentication is used it will be hard to help you.

Comment: It says  HTTP BASIC authentication what should I be choosing

Comment: @kat1330 Can you please suggest howcan I do the HTTP Basic Authentication as its the Rest API

Comment: @user4912134 I cannot just answer to your question because it looks like you struggling with multiple problems and my answer can be downvoted from community. What I can recommend to you is to download Postman and try to make authorized request. Once you make successful request then you will know what you need to do with your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username:password")));
```

Comment: I tried this. The API I am calling is the REST API so is there something else should I be doing for authentication